# Lerna add will not add internal dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, lerna

I'm using lerna to manage a React component library. Some of my components have both external dependencies from the npm registry as well as internal dependencies, sibling packages in the repository.

[image: Directory structure]

I'm attempting to add internal dependencies to another package using the `lerna add` command. Specifically I want to add Utils, Typography, Link, to HRWrapper.

**To add Utils I run**:

```
lerna add Utils --scope=HRWrapper
```

**and receive this error**:

```
lerna notice cli v3.2.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna WARN No packages found where Utils can be added.
```

**To install Typography I run**:

```
lerna add Typography --scope=HRWrapper
```

**and receive this error**:

```
lerna notice cli v3.2.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna ERR! Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Typography - Not found
lerna ERR!     at res.buffer.catch.then.body (/Users/powje6f/sites/vz-react/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:104:15)
lerna ERR! lerna 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Typography - Not found
```

I'm not sure what the first error means when trying to install Utils. But, for some reason when I try to add Typography it's searching for it in the npm registry.

**Here is my lerna.json**:

```
{
  "lerna": "2.10.0",
  "packages": ["packages/**/*"],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I also run across the similar trouble. you can try this:

```js
lerna add module-1 packages/prefix-*       Adds the module-1 package to the packages in the 'prefix-' prefixed folders
```

```js
// Utils
lerna add Utils packages/HRWrapper

// Typography
lerna add Typography packages/HRWrapper
```

this way is working for me.

```js
lerna add module-1 --scope=module-2
```

*I guess the reason why not work normally is:*

*Only if `module-1` already was registered on NPM, it is available.*

Comment: For further info see the official [Lerna 'add 'documentation](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/add).